# How to Insert Data From One Table to Another With Matching the Columns Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Date | Parameter A |
| --- | --- |
| 2022.12.05 08:00:00 | 3 |
| 2022.12.05 08:15:00 | 4 |
| 2022.12.05 08:45:00 | 7 |

| Date | Parameter A |
| --- | --- |
| 2022.12.05 08:00:00 |  |
| 2022.12.05 08:15:00 |  |
| 2022.12.05 08:30:00 |  |
| 2022.12.05 08:45:00 |  |

I have 2 tables, the first one is the data table that I get daily from a source and the second one is a static date table where there are date information for every 15 minutes.

The problem is, as you can see in the first table, I didn't get 08:30 info because there wasn't parameter information in the source.

How can I insert the data with matching dates? And If there is no info at a specific time, I want it to insert "No Data" to that row.

The final table should look like this;

| Date | Parameter A |
| --- | --- |
| 2022.12.05 08:00:00 | 3 |
| 2022.12.05 08:15:00 | 4 |
| 2022.12.05 08:30:00 | No Data |
| 2022.12.05 08:45:00 | 7 |

Thank you.

I tried to use "Vlookup" function but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work below. When you say your VLOOKUP didn't work what happened? Those types of things are helpful to help us help you. Also it doesn't hurt to show us what you tried.
Hope this helps!

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$D:$e,2,0),"No Data")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. My mistake I didn't write what happened when I tried to solve the problem using VLOOKUP.

Firstly, I didn't know that I had to use IFERROR.

Secondly, static value (like "date" as I mentioned in the question) and the number of the parameters may vary depending on the data type. When I have not only one but two different static value or more e.g. date and cell, and different parameters, I get the "There's a problem with this formula" error. Means I probably use the formula wrong :)

Still can't figure it out though.